# Short story where dolphins repopulate the land

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to recall a story where humans have died off.  Dolphins are repopulating the land and a series of surgical procedures is involved.  The final procedure is to close the blowhole.

There may have been a "love story" where one dolphin was going on land and the other was staying behind.

I believe that this was in a collection of short stories (possibly including "Examination Day") from the mid seventies.  The story would have been targeted at seventh and eight graders.

Comment: Looked through IO9's [_"10 of the most epic science fictional dolphins"_](http://io9.com/5813477/10-of-the-most-epic-science-fictional-dolphins), found zilch.

Comment: @unclebrad Any reason why you haven't awarded a correct answer or investigated my answer?

Comment: I second that. If @JMFBs answer is the right one, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: @unclebrad Is my answer lacking in some way?

Answer (score 11):

*Destiny and the Dolphins* (1969) by Roy Meyers.

A nuclear holocaust destroys everything. There's only three humans left I believe and they repopulate the Earth.

[This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003SKPTIM) is the only review I could find of it that references what the story is about. It's the third book in the *Dolphin Trilogy*.

> In Destiny and the Dolphins, a nuclear holocaust destroys all of civilization, leaving the three of them to repopulate the world. It is up to them to work out how they will engineer a new society.

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising.  I will check it out.

Comment: @unclebrad did you ever look into it? Was this the correct answer?

Comment: @JMFB : Nice find, JMFB!  +1. This is almost certainly the correct answer.  I'm surprised it hasn't been accepted (or at least confirmed) yet by the OP.